# Vue 3, Composition Api two way data binding on 'reactive' not working correctly

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

i am new in `vue 3` and trying to make two data binding, but it's not working correctly. I did `setup()` and create a `reactive` data. Bind it to the children via `v-model`. Then $emit the updated data back to the parent. But parent's `reactive` data not applied 'till code re-run on save command.

**parent script:**

```js
    export default defineComponent({
      setup(){
        const activeCard = reactive({id:null, travelType:null})
        return {activeCard}
      },
    })
```

**parent template:**

```html
    <pin-card v-for="(pinCard, idx) in categoryPinCards"
              :key="idx"
              v-model="activeCard"
              :pinCard="pinCard"></pin-card>
```

**child script**

```js
    export default defineComponent({
      props:{
        modelValue:Object,
      },
      methods:{
        makePinActive(id:number, travelType:null) {
          this.$emit("update:modelValue", {id: id, travelType: travelType})
        },
      }
    })
```

I followed the steps but, something is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `reactive` props can't be used by `v-model` in Vue 3 (while `ref`s don't have this problem).

A workaround is to add a handler for the `update:modelValue` event that `Object.assigns` the new value:

```html
<pin-card
    v-for="(pinCard, idx) in categoryPinCards"
    :key="idx"
    :modelValue="activeCard" 
    @update:modelValue="setActiveCard($event)" 
    :pinCard="pinCard"
></pin-card>
```

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      //...
      setActiveCard(eventData) {
        Object.assign(activeCard, eventData)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-reactive-with-v-model-63imx?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: Oh I see, and additionally I tried another approach. still using the reactive but when I bind the data via `v-model`, not binding it as an object directly. I am binding it more then one v-model, such as `v-model:activeId=activeCard.id` and `v-model:activeType=activeCard.travelType`... so that I can $emit the data back to parent one by one... in the end solved the problem. But thank you for showing another workaround. appreciate it!

Comment: Ah, that's probably a better workaround :)